# LaTeX (beamer) -- Is there a way to suppress the caption tag of "Figure X:" or "Table X:"?

Tags: latex, beamer

I am making a beamer presentation of someone else's research paper (so I don't have the original tex code). I am using pdfs of the tables in the presentation but wanted to cut out all of the original captions, which can be a bit wordy for a slideshow, and simply label them with either "Table X" or "Figure X" along with the title.

So I'd like to suppress automatically inserted caption label. If I put the title/label without the `\caption{}` function, then I have to fight with word wrapping.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a site for Tex and LaTeX questions, you're probably more successful there -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you came across this, here's answer at [tex stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3303/latex-beamer-is-there-a-way-to-suppress-the-caption-label-of-figure-x-or) (via Juan A Navarro):